# blackberry list contacts with email address

Tags: email, blackberry, contacts

I am using this code snippet to retrieve contact's email addressees but what I want to do is list the contacts who has got email address. With this method it displays all of the contacts

```
try {
                list = (BlackBerryContactList) PIM.getInstance()
                .openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);

                PIMItem contact = list.choose();
                if (contact != null) {
                    String emailId = "";

                    for (int i = 0; i < contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL); i++) {
                        emailId = contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, i);
                        System.out.println("_ _ _  _ __  EMAIL : " + i + " " +  emailId);
                    }
                }
            } catch (PIMException e) {
                Dialog.inform("Proble creating contact list!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below the function which return only those contact list which contains email address:

```
/*import email id from the contact list. */

public Vector getEmail()
{

    Vector emailList=new Vector();//contains the list of contact
    email_list.removeAllElements();
    try
    {
        PIM pim = PIM.getInstance();
        ContactList contacts;
        contacts = (ContactList) pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
        Enumeration items;
        items = contacts.items();

        while(items.hasMoreElements())
        {
            Contact contact = (Contact) items.nextElement();

            String emailID = "";
            if (contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.EMAIL) && (contact.countValues(Contact.EMAIL) > 0) ) 
            {   
                 emailID=contact.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 0);

                //emailList.addElement(arr);
            }
            String firstName = "";
            if ((contacts.isSupportedField(Contact.NAME)) && (contact.countValues(Contact.NAME) > 0))
            {
                String[] name = contact.getStringArray(Contact.NAME, 0);
                firstName = name[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
              //  String lastName = name[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];
            }
            String arr[]={emailID,firstName};//array which contains emailid and first name
            emailList.addElement(arr);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception pe)
    {
    }
    return emailList;
}
```

Comment: this is good solution but is it possible to pass some parameters to the contacts application and get the desired result?

Comment: Above method return the all contact list which have email id. Now you are able to modify above code according to your requirements. By the way, what type of result you want. plz decribe

Comment: I know how to retrieve contacts with email. I want the inbuilt contacts application to list contacts with email. is it possible?

Comment: here by believe that the stock contacts app can not list contacts with email but Vivek's answer is appropriate to marking it.